# Need to convert a table rows to column in another table based on Table 1 elements condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables T1 and T2.
I want to insert data into T2 based on conditions of T1.

Say T1 has data

```
SID LinkName           
S1  Link1           
S1  Link2           
S2  Link1           
S2  Link2          
S2  Link3         
S3  Link2
```

I want to insert data into a new table T2 having above Link1, Link2 etc as columns in such a way that if S1 has link 1 then its column for Link1 would show Yes and so on. 
Example for S3, column of Link1 and Link3 will show NO, Link2 Column will show YES

```
SID Link1   Link2   Link3                   
S1  Yes Yes No                   
S2  Yes Yes Yes                  
S3  No  Yes No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run a query:

```
select sid,
       max(case when LinkName = 'Link1' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as Link1,
       max(case when LinkName = 'Link2' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as Link2,
       max(case when LinkName = 'Link3' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as Link3
from t1
group by sid;
```

You can use `create table as` or `insert` to add this information to another table.

Note:  This uses the fact that `'yes'` > `'no'`.